# Is there a Command Which Shows How Much Time the Last "n" Commands Take to Run?

Tags: python, linux, performance, bash

I am running different Python scripts in Linux and I want to see how much time these scripts, I wonder if there is a command in Bash or in Python it doesn't depend to echo or print to the screen how much time it took to run the command. Thanks in advance.

**For example the Python script might be :**

```
import subprocess

command = ['sudo', '-S', 'iwlist', 'wlan0', 'scan']
output = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
data = []
for cell_item in output.split("Cell"):
    data_item = []
    for line in cell_item.split("\n"):
        if any(item in line for item in ["ESSID", "Quality", "Pairwise"]):
            data_item.append(line.strip())
    if data_item:
        data.append(data_item)
print data
```

**What I want is to see on the screen under the last line of some code outputs, I want to see there i.e. ; "This Code Lasted 16.363 seconds"** [image]

Comment: Use the `time` command in UNXI.

Comment: Or the [`time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) Python library

Comment: But can I see how much time the earlier commands take with that?

Comment: Python doesn't time itself by default, so any timing you do has to be explicit.

Comment: Thank you for that, 'time python script.py' worked well, and if I import time in the script, does it save the time it took to run that code and if I can learn how much that code took to run last time without running the code?

Comment: Use a profiler.   Man there are so many different ways to do this.   https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: @TolgaVarol what do you mean *"earlier commands"*? Just importing `time` won't help, you need to **use it**.

Comment: @TolgaVarol if you did not explicitly use `time` or something similar on a piece of code, you cannot retroactively find out how long it took.

Comment: @jonrsharpe by earlier commands, like I ran 10 scripts, and I want to learn all of them how much time it took to run without running them again

Comment: @TheSoundDefense how can I find out how long it took retroactively if I imported time in the command earlier?

Comment: @TolgaVarol if all you did was `import time`, then you can't.

Comment: @TolgaVarol you can't retroactively time something you ran in the past - how would that even work?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought maybe all the activities are automatically saved in somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the comments, the question appears to be "how can I retroactively see how long my previous commands took?" The answer is simple: **you can't.**

Python does not automatically time itself when it's running code, and all `import time` will do is give you access to functions to do the timing yourself. If you ever want to know how long something takes, you have to explicitly say so before the fact. After the code is run, I can't think of anything that will go back and determine how long it took to run. I believe you're going to have to do all of your timing again, sorry to say.

Answer (score 3):

Just put `time` before any other command or script e.g.:

```
time sleep 4
```

gives

```
real    0m4.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.001s
```

You can change format of the output as well, see `man time`.

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2):

Personally I use:

```
from datetime import datetime

t1 = datetime.now()
bashCommand = "df -h > space.txt"
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
t2 = datetime.now()
total = t2-t1

print total
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bash's special variable SECONDS:

```
SECONDS=0
script.py
echo $SECONDS
```